# Editing the bootstrap classes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am a beginner at Bootstrap, and now I'm learning Bootstrap

and I have a question about editing the bootstrap classes

I want edit the bootstrap classes For example  I want change the border size and color ,

I create the file (main.css) and call class For example :table 
and define the new border and color in main.css:

```
.table{
border : 2px solid red;
}
```

but this code in the main.css dont work !
It should be noted i call the main.css file in my html with this code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
```

Comment: `border:2px solid;` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border

Comment: try adding !important to the property as, .table{ border:2px solid red !important};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using the same selector classes that are affect the element you want to change the border for (you can check this using inspection tools in a browser and looking at the CSS), make sure that you are including your own CSS file **AFTER** bootstrap.

Please also note that some bootstrap classes have !important included on some of the style rules, this means that the rule will not be overridden by CSS without an !important attribute (.table does not have this, but you may change a class that does later on).

Another factor to consider is that your browser may be caching your CSS files, as such any changes may not be shown in your browser. You should clear this cache to see if it helps.

Comment: This is the way to go! I got to agree `!important` is a valid solution, but also a dirty workaround. That I wouldn't suggest.

Comment: Thanks your Description is perfect

Answer (score 1):

Class with name `.table` is very generic you might need to think again in the naming convention.

html

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-bordered--custom">...<table>
```

css

```
.table-bordered--custom td, .table-bordered--custom th {
    border: 2px solid red !important;
}
```

https://codepen.io/omarmakled/pen/xeazpY

https://seesparkbox.com/foundry/bem_by_example

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/tables/

Comment: The class .table is used within bootstrap, it is the original poster's wishes to replace styles within this class with their own, as such they should use the same selectors. in this case that would be the .table class.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to call your main.css file after the bootstrap file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
```

Alternatively, you can add an !important statement:

```
.table{
border : 2px solid red !important;
}
```